# Open EditForm instead of DisplayForm on Title click in SharePoint list 2013

Tags: list, powershell, list-form

I have a SharePoint list and in that there is a `Title` field. By default when we click on title it opens DisplayForm.aspx. Insted of this I want to open EditForm.aspx using `Powershell Script` or any other way using SPD.

Thanks.

Comment: You will have a field Title(linked to item in edit menu) in list of fields that appears in modify view page.

Comment: I have tried but still its opening in View mode only and I have SP 2013

Comment: Please check the below link. jQuery to achieve the same. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c9c54d3c-c9ab-4460-95c6-54a649d8a28d/open-edit-form-directly-when-list-item-is-clicked-in-sharepoint-2013-list?forum=sharepointgeneral

Comment: @User2809 's suggestion should work...I tried implementing same and it worked wonders for me....

Comment: You can add the Edit icon in the view and not change the standard. Is very usable.

Comment: @User2809- that javascript will work for single page only. If we have 30 items per page it will work fine. But if change the page it will not work. I have tried this 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views
Its working fine for single view. But for all view i have tried to put it in master page but some how js isnt loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct and recommended way would be to use the Client Side Rendering feature of SharePoint 2013. You can refer to Item Link example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views) for achieving this.
Client Side rendering is powerful alternative to XSLT modifications and is wonderfully explained by Andrei Markeev in the article linked above.

Comment: Thanks. It works fine for single view. Also i have tried to put that code in master page for all views. But somehow its not working.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new data view page in SharePoint designer and edit the link inside it to refer to edit form instead of display form,

Comment: Is there any way to maintain the functionality of the ribbon and item dropdown in a custom dataview?

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question, but one that I was recently researching and came up with a SPD Workflow solution to my problem.

1. Create a hyperlink Column in the List (field)
2. Right-click on the "edit" button and copy shortcut, paste to notepad
3. Remove the number following "ID=" at the end of the URL
4. Create a new workflow and set to Start automatically when an item is created
5. Create a Local Variable (V1)

Then add these two lines to your workflow

- Set Variable: V1 to https://'site'/listform.aspx?PageType=6&ListId={blahblahblah}&ID=[%Current Item:ID%], [%Current Item:Title%]
- then Set Field to Variable: V1

Now remove the original Title column with the hyperlink Field column on your list views and it will show up as a link to the edit menu for each of the entries on the list.